# Hilbert Theorem of zeros

Tags: commutative-algebra

Use the Hilbert Nullstellensatz Theorem to prove the following result:

> Given $F_1, F_2, F_3 \in \mathbb{C} [X_1,\dots,X_n]$ polynomials checking the following conditions:
>
> 1. $F_1$ is irreducible;
> 2. $F_2$ is not a multiple of $F_1$;
> 3. For every element $ x \in \mathbb{C}^n \text{ if } F_1 (x) = 0 \text{ and } F_3 (x) \neq 0,\text{ then } F_2 (x) = 0$.
>
> Show that $F_3$ is a multiple of $F_1$.

Comment: Cuidado: se te colaron algunas palabras en castellano...;)

Comment: You still have some words in spanish in there, yet the problem is a little confusing: if we want to prove that $\,F_3=kF_1\;,\;\;k\,$ a scalar, then condition (3) is fulfilled vacuously...

Comment: Note: The theorem you're referring to is known in English (!) as the [Nullstellensatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz).

Comment: Why does it say "Nullstellensatz-Henning Makholm Thorem" @HenningMakholm ?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Looks like the OP mistook my signature for part of the name of the theorem I provided. (I wouldn't want my name attached to that theorem -- I can never even remember what it says without looking it up).

Comment: I think that this problem is related to the definition of prime element, so, p | ab  $\Leftrightarrow$ p | a ó p | b , but I don't know how connect my exercise with this definition

Comment: Condition 3 states that if $F_1(x)=0$ then $F_3(x)=0$ or $F_2(x)=0$.  In particular if $F_1(x)=0$ then $F_2(x)F_3(x)=0$.  Now apply the Nullstellensatz to get a condition involving the ideal generated by $F_1$ and the ideal generated by $F_2F_3$.

Comment: The condition 3 is correct, I can't do anything. Sorry

Comment: The condition $3$ as it is stated is **obviously wrong**: how can you pretend to obtain that $F_3$ is a multiple of $F_1$, but in the same time there exists $x\in\mathbb C^n$ such that $F_1 (x) = 0 \text{ and } F_3 (x) \neq 0$? Ah, sure, a false statement can imply a correct one!

Answer (score 3):

If the condition $3.$ states (as @JeffTolliver suggested in his comment) that $F_1(x)=0$ implies $F_2(x)F_3(x)=0$, then all is easy: this condition means $\mathcal V(F_1)\subset\mathcal V(F_2F_3)$ and then $\mathcal I(\mathcal V(F_2F_3))\subseteq\mathcal I(\mathcal V(F_1))$, that is, $\sqrt{(F_2F_3)}\subseteq\sqrt{(F_1)}$. Since $F_1$ is irreducible the ideal $(F_1)$ is prime, and thus $F_2F_3\in (F_1)$. It follows that $F_1\mid F_2F_3$, and from the condition $2.$ we get $F_1\mid F_3$.